# how to resolve "InnoDB: Error (Duplicate key) writing word node to FTS auxiliary index table" in mysql

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am continuous getting above error in mysqld log. Please tell me what is this error about and how to solve it. I am using mysql 5.7 (not mariadb)

Answer (score 2):

A guess:  A `FULLTEXT` index on that table is corrupted.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

should rebuild the FT index, thereby fixing the problem.

If that is not sufficient, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; there may be some other clues there.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE` didn't seem to do anything for me (MySQL 8.10 w/INNODB) but `OPTIMIZE TABLE` did. Note: it was a blocking action and took our chat server offline for 7.5 hours.